# Cloud scheduler - HTTP - list in payload/body

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, cloud, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I have a scheduled job in GCP that POSTs to the endpoint of a REST service. The payload expected by the url is

```
{"foo": ["bar"]}
```

I specified `"{\"foo\": \[\"bar\"\]}"` in the Body field in the web console :
[image]

AND specified `application/json` in the `Content-Type` header.

But I get 400 error from the endpoint (Bad request). The endpoint is working perfectly fine when requested from the swagger, so I think the problem comes from how I specify the payload in the cron job.

How should I write the payload in Cloud Scheduler web interface ?

Comment: Why you didn't specify the raw json `{"foo": ["bar"]}`?

Comment: thank you it worked like you suggested. I copied the payload I would pass with gcloud, in which I specify the backslashes.

Comment: Perfect. I posted as answer to help the others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use you raw JSON `{"foo": ["bar"]}`. The escape characters are for gcloud CLI.